# Check if data (heap) is actually swapped out?

Tags: linux, winapi

Is it possible, in Linux or Windows to check "in advance", if a piece of memory is swapped out?  That is, without accessing it and then notice that data is being brought in from disk...

Comment: Even if you could, what would you do with the result? It may be invalid by the very next instruction that your process is executing.

Comment: Indeed, but one can try. I am not looking for anything perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under linux you can use [`mincore`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mincore.2.html) to determine if pages are currently in RAM.

Comment: Thanks! So you can and since a long time ago... :)

Comment: For Windows I can't really find a direct equivalent, `QueryWorkingSet` gives you information on all pages, although `QueryWorkingSetEx` does, but that doesn't exist everywhere